# How can I efficiently store pseudo queries to the database inside their own table, and how to correctly store items with varying attributes?

Tags: php, mysql

First, I wish to apologize if the title is vague, the question is hard to summarize - please feel free to edit as appropriate.

In a website I am building, I have products within categories (and the categories are being expanded constantly) that have attributes (I can't think of a better word, I apologize for the fact that this crosses with database terminology, but I mean attribute as in color, size, weight, not as in a field of a database table).  Those attributes may or may not be defined depending on the category, and sometimes specifically the product.

Now, individuals using the website will want to create a query that searches for items matching specific attributes (think "is green, weighs less than 4 lbs., rated 3 stars or higher"), and save that query in the database as a tuple of a table that they can reference.  Mind that these will be end-users, so they will not be able to actually write the query themselves.  Also note that there may be a great deal of redundancy in some types of queries, and that there will be many more of these queries than there are items.

---

My first thought:

Store the items all in one table (`items`), with an `id`, `category id`, `name`.  Store attributes types in `attribute_types` with `id`, `name`, `type` (which would be int, string, enum, etc).  Store attributes in a separate table with `item_id`, `attribute_type_id`, and `value`.

Then, create the query based on HTML selections as though I were actually querying the database, save the exact query, and store it as a string in a table with an `id` and `query`.  Check for the existence of a query before storing it.

---

This seems as though it would work, but I can't immagine that this is the best way to go about it.  Is there a more efficient, or frankly less ugly, solution?  Am I even storing the items in an appropriate manner?

Thank you,
James

Comment: i have done it in the past, it has its pro's and con's like everything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of specific attributes and categories is small enough, this is usually solved using [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) (or some [other](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) [derivation](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) of it), if not you need an [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) model - which is difficult to do complex queries with and, in the long run, can lead to [GIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) pretty fast.

[image: Magento DB Schema]

Another alternative approach is to use schemaless datastores, [such as MongoDB](http://kylebanker.com/blog/2010/04/30/mongodb-and-ecommerce/) or serialized blobs.